# Angular 4 ngFor does not work when remapping source array keys

Tags: angular

I'm trying to rewrite a list used for rendering an html select element so that its keys matches up with the primary identifier of the list object type.

```
export class Industry {
  constructor(
    public industryId?: number,
    public code?: number,
    public description?: string
  ) { }
}
```

In my form:

```
<select formControlName="industryId" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let i of industries" [ngValue]="i.industryId">{{i.description}}</option>
</select>
```

When I assign the array that I obtain from a service all is well but when I rewrite it to an associative array so the keys match the primary identifier it renders a select list with the correct number of options but no values.

```
private getIndustries() {
  this.industryService.getIndustries()
    .subscribe(
      industries => {
        // this works
        this.industries = industries;

        // this does not work
        this.industries = [];
        for (let item of industries) {
          this.industries[item['industryId']] = item;
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: You can not use object maps with ngFor. It should be raising an error on this for you.

Comment: You could try using a Map class and then in your template `industries.values()`

Comment: you are not pushing any values into your `industries` array variable

Comment: @Aravind I am not pushing because I want the array key to match the object's primary key. The values are present when I console.log them. They are not showing up in the option of the html list.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Thank you your suggestion works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no associative array concept in JS. You can't do this straight away. Make this into array of objects. In object you can add key dynamically and then access it like 
this..

For Eg:

```
this.industry = [];
    this.obj = {};
    for (let item of industries) {
          this.obj[item['industryId']] = item;
        };
In the view you can use ngFor to iterate get the value as follows...
    this.industry.push(obj);
```